# bash: Apostrophe in path

Tags: bash, path, escaping

On Mac OS X (bash 4.2), I try to cd into a folder with an apostrophe in the path:

```
cd "~/Documents/study/new/Beej's Guide to Unix IPC_code/examples"
```

Then I got

```
-bash: cd: ~/Documents/study/new/Beej's Guide to Unix IPC_code/examples: No such file or directory
```

I also tried escaping the apostrophe like this:

```
cd "~/Documents/study/new/Beej\'s Guide to Unix IPC_code/examples"
```

with the result:

```
-bash: cd: ~/Documents/study/new/Beej\'s Guide to Unix IPC_code/examples: No such file or directory
```

The only thing worked for me was hard escaping the white spaces and the apostrophe without double-quotes around like this:

```
cd ~/Documents/study/new/Beej\'s\ Guide\ to\ Unix\ IPC_code/examples
```

In this case, is there a way I can avoid hard escaping at all?

Comment: Weird. I can do that with bash 3.2.48 (default on OS X 10.8.3). During autocomplete, the apostrophe was hard escaped for me even though I used double quotes. Are you sure your `cd` command looked precisely that way? Also: are you sure it's an apostrophe and not a backtick or something similar?

Comment: You are quoting the tilde character. This won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tilde (`~`) won't be expanded inside quotes, so you need to leave it outside the quotes. Any of these will work:

```
cd ~/"Documents/study/new/Beej's Guide to Unix IPC_code/examples"
cd ~/Documents/study/new/"Beej's Guide to Unix IPC_code"/examples
cd ~/Documents/study/new/Beej"'s Guide to Unix "IPC_code/examples
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of bash do you have ? Like @MaxLeske said, it works with autocomplete on version 3.2.48.

Remove the tilde (~) character inside the double quote. Instead give a full path.

```
cd "/Users/<uname>/Documents/study/new/Beej's Guide to Unix IPC_code/examples"
```